# Swift: Run function after collecting item

Tags: ios, swift, skspritenode, sknode

I have a class that creates collectable items:

```
class CollectableCreate {

    var collectable = SKSpriteNode()
    var type = String()

    var onCollect : () -> Void = {}

    init(type: String, position: CGPoint, text: String = "This collectable uses no text!", onCollect : () -> Void) {

        self.type = type.lowercaseString

        switch self.type {

            default:
                collectable.size = CGSize(width: 1, height: 200)
                collectable.color = SKColor.blueColor()
                collectable.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: collectable.size)
                break
        }

        collectable.position = position

        collectable.name = self.type
        collectable.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Collectable
        collectable.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player
        collectable.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player


        self.onCollect = onCollect
    }


    func chatBoxActivate() -> SKSpriteNode {
        collectable.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        collectable.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        return collectable
    }

    func collect() {
        self.onCollect()
    }

}
```

I create the collectable item like this:

```
let d = CollectableCreate(type: "chatbox", position: CGPoint(x: 500, y: 100), onCollect: {
        self.createChatBox("test blalb|blablalba")
    })

self.addChild(d.chatBoxActivate())
```

And on didBeginContact I have this:

```
if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Collectable || secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Collectable) {

    let collectableBody = (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Collectable ? firstBody.node : secondBody.node)
    //collectableBody.collect() <---                
    collectableBody?.removeFromParent()

}
```

I want to run the `CollectableCreate().collect()` function when I run into a collectable. How to I make this happen?

Comment: `collectableBody` seems to be an optional at that point, so have you tried `collectableBody?.collect()` (note the question mark)?

Comment: "Value of type 'SKNode' has no member 'collect'"

Comment: So `collectableBody` is of type `SKNode?`. Is that what you expect? If not, why not? Did you (or one of the libraries you use) extend `SKNode` with a method named `collect`? If not, there's your answer why it doesn't work. The code you posted really doesn't help us help you answer these questions. Try to follow the clues the compiler gives you with its error messages. Option-click an identifier in Xcode to see what type the compiler has inferred for that variable and compare that with your expectations.

Comment: Yeah, it's declared that it is a SKNode at `let collectableBody = (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Collectable ? firstBody.node : secondBody.node)`. I want to know how I can be able to run the `collect()` function of the node's Class.

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  You have `let d = CollectableCreate(...` and object `d` implements the method you want to call, but I don't see anything that preserves `d` or makes it accessible from a `collectableBody`.

Comment: I want to run the function when the player collides why **any** object of type "Collectable", not just the `d` object

Comment: You've defined it as an instance method and tied it to the creation of an object.  Therefore, you need a reference to a `CollectableCreate` instance to execute it whether you call it `d` or anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid i'm shooting in the dark here since i've never worked with `SpriteKit`, so please feel free to add to/or edit my answer.

You should subclass `SKSpriteNode`:

```
class Collectable : SKSpriteNode {

    var type: String?
    var onCollect: (() -> ())?

    convenience init(type: String, position: CGPoint, text: String = "This collectable uses no text!", onCollect : () -> Void) {
        self.init()

        self.type = type.lowercaseString

        switch self.type {

        default:
            self.size = CGSize(width: 1, height: 200)
            self.color = SKColor.blueColor()
            self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: self.size)
            break
        }

        self.position = position

        self.name = self.type
        self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Collectable
        self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player
        self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player


        self.onCollect = onCollect
    }

    func chatBoxActivate() -> SKSpriteNode {
        self.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

        return self
    }

    func collect(){
        self.onCollect?()
    }
}
```

And use it in the following matter, and add whatever class you are subclassing in your controller, and add the correct delegates:

```
class SomeClass {

    func someFunc(){

        let collectable = Collectable(type: "chatbox", position: CGPoint(x: 500, y: 100), onCollect: {
            self.createChatBox("FooBar")
        })

        self.addChild(collectable.chatBoxActivate())
    }

    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact){

        let firstBody = contact.bodyA
        let secondBody = contact.bodyB

        if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Collectable || secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Collectable) {

            let collectableBody = firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Collectable ? firstBody.node : secondBody.node

            if let collectable = collectableBody as? Collectable {
                collectable.collect()
            }

            collectableBody?.removeFromParent()

        }

    }

    func addChild(collectable: SKSpriteNode){
        // Some logic
    }

    func createChatBox(text: String) {
        // Some logic
    }

}
```

Hope this can point you in the right direction!

[SpriteKit Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SpriteKitFramework_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013041)

Comment: I can't tell how much you helped me! I tried to subclass SKSpriteNode, but I was getting a lot of problems with the init function. Your answer is perfect, thank you